# how to make value required for items created with the help of apex_item API in oracle apex 5

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

how to set value `required=yes` for items created with APEX_ITEM in apex5.0

```
APEX_ITEM.TEXT (p_idx =>2 ,  p_item_id =>  ISSUED_TO) TO from ISSUED_INFO,
```

this item should be

Answer (score 0):

have you tried p_attributes? It might be possible like this:

```
  APEX_ITEM.TEXT(p_idx =>2 ,  p_item_id =>  ISSUED_TO , p_attributes=> 'required="" aria-required="true"')
```